# Uploading supplementary material to figshare. How to refer to it before making it visible to the public?

Tags: data, online-publication, online-resource

My problem is the following: We want to upload supplementary material for bookchapters I'm editing. We have decided to use figshare.com for this. One advantage is that they supply all material with a DOI. **But** (as far as I understand) they do only so when material is made available for the public, not for private data.

Now, it would be a little strange to make supplementary material available a long time before publication (possibly more than a year).

How may I obtain a permanent reference (doi, link, etc) to the supplementary material which I can add to the respective bookchapter already without making said supplements visible to the public?

And if this is not possible, what would be a workaround? Make it public just shortly before handing in the edited volume to our publisher (this would still be months before the publication date)? Just refer to the account (not a single file) on figshare the material will be hosted on? Include a placeholder DOI within the chapter and include it after we received page proofs from the publisher? Just publish the supplementary material already because nobody cares?

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the Edit Item screen is an option to create a private link. There's [more info about private links on their blog](https://figshare.com/blog/figshare_new_features_Get_DOI_or_private_sharing_link/135).

For peer review, the private link feature has the added advantage that it hides the author information.